# Cassandra - difference in efficiency between simple and compound key

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I have a problem with understanding a one thing from this article - http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

Exercise - We want get all users by groupname.

Solution:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    groupname text,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (groupname, username)
);

SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupname = 'footballers';
```

But to find all users in group we can set: `PRIMARY KEY (groupname)` and it work's also.

Why is needed in this case a clustering key (username)? I know that when we set username as the clustering key we can use it in a `WHERE` clause. But to find users only by groupname is any difference between `PRIMARY KEY (groupname)` and `PRIMARY KEY (groupname, username)` in terms of query efficiency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clustering keys provide multiple benefits: Query flexibility, result set ordering (within a partition key) and extended uniqueness.

> But to find all users in group we can set: `PRIMARY KEY (groupname)`

Try that once.  Create a new table using only `groupname` as your PRIMARY KEY, and then try to insert multiple `username`s for each group.  You will find that there will only ever be one group, and that the `username` column will be overwritten for each new user within that group.

> But to find users only by `groupname` is any difference between `PRIMARY KEY (groupname)` and `PRIMARY KEY (groupname, username)` in terms of query efficiency?

If `PRIMARY KEY (groupname)` performs faster, the most-likely reason is because there can be only a single row returned.

In this case, defining  `username` as a clustering key provides:

1. The ability to sort by `username` within a group.
2. The ability to query for a specific `username` within a group.
3. The ability to add multiple `username`s within a group.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the clustering key if you want to query by groupname.

If you add a clustering key (username in this exemple) rows will be ordered by username for a groupname.

Comment: Ok, I understand but whether this ordering makes that searching users by groupname is faster?

Comment: No it changes nothing. Clustering order garantie on-disk order so your record are always sorted. But ascending order are most efficent than descending order.